# How to not automatically unmount eCryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

I am using eCryptfs and I would like to do either/or these things:

1. Not automatically unmount the private directory when the user logs out 2. Mount another users private directory so I can just use a script and logout (from root possibly).

The reason for this is so I can have Gitolite access the directory when no one is logged in after I mount the filesystem. I may do something similar for `www-data`.

Comment: What is the point of keeping public_html inside an ecryptfs filesystem, anyway?

Comment: @grawity: I cant think of any reason but i'll still need it for git. I dont even want redmine with git so i probably dont need to bother with www-data and encryption.

Answer (score 3):

delete `~/.ecryptfs/auto_umount`. Its an empty file so you can restore it with touch

Answer (score 0):

According [to a user at Ask Ubuntu it’s a known bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/932650). Don’t know if it’s true or not, but I found a workaround.

I added at the end of my `.bash_logout` (e.g. `vim ~/.bash_logout`) following line:

```
(sleep 10; ecryptfs-umount-private) &
```

When I log out (via ssh connection), I see the message “Sessions still open, not unmounting,” but my home-dir gets unmounted/encrypted anyways.